# how to get the acknowledgement of message received

Tags: android, activemq-classic, mqtt

i am using `MQTT` library in android with `Apache Active MQ`. i am able to subscribe and publish messages but i don;t know how can i get the message id and the acknowledgement that the subscribers has received the message.

in `publishArrived` i am getting following information

```
topicName 
payload,
qos,
retained
```

but inside payload i am just getting string message i am sending , how can i extract the following information.
i think using these fields i can get the acknowledgement.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in acknowledge to a publisher that a consumer has received a message, this is something that you need to implement yourself.  You could have your consumer send a message to a response topic that the send listens on if you really need to know.

Comment: if is specify QoS level to 1 then `the broker/client will deliver the message at least once, with confirmation required` right ? so do i need to still implement it manually ?

Comment: The confirmation only tells you that the broker has received and processed the message, not that the consumer has actually received it.

Comment: so is there any way ? to get it ? i switched to mqtt bcoz xmpp has more round trips to the server

Comment: The only way is to implement your own request / response solution.  The whole idea of a message broker is to decouple the senders and receivers.